# Cannot install a package on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-sources

I would like to install `dconf-editor` on Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit. [This tutorial](https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-17-04-lts-Zesty-Zapus/installing-dconf-editor-on-ubuntu17.04.html) suggests it should be pretty easy - running `apt install dconf-editor` should be sufficient. It does not work however and prints this message instead:

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package dconf-editor
> ```

What happened to the `dconf-editor` package?

---

#### Additional details

- `apt-cache policy dconf-editor` returns:

  > N: Unable to locate package dconf-editor
- `apt update` does not help.

Comment: Is your source updated (`apt update`)? what is the output of `apt-cache policy dconf-editor`?

Comment: what is the output of : `grep  "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Make sure the repository **Universe** is enabled at *System settings > Software and updates*

Comment: @Ravexina I guess you nailed it. I accidentally overwritten `/etc/apt/sources.list` and its missing the default repositories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `rmadison` installed you can simply run:

```
rmadison dconf-editor | grep zesty
```

to find out if this package is available for `zesty`. here is my output:

```
 dconf-editor | 3.23.4-0ubuntu1 | zesty/universe   | source, amd64, arm64, ...
```

So it's there and it's in `universe` component; to find out if you have access to install it run:

```
apt-cache policy dconf-editor
```

If you get nothing, I guess something is wrong with your `sources.list`, run:

```
grep "^deb " /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to check your `sources.list` file; you should have some lines look like this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
```

If you dont, add them, update your sources; then install the program.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my `/etc/apt/sources.list` didn't have the default repositories - they must have been overwritten - and this is why I couldn't install anything with `apt`.

The solution is to restore the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

1. If you're lucky then you've got a backup file `/etc/apt/sources.list.save` from which you can restore the list of repositories.
2. Otherwise, I've found this website which is able to generate a list of repositories from scratch: https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/.
3. Also as Ravexina added in the comments:

   > You can also use this file to restore your sources: `/usr/share/doc/apt/examples/sources.list`, just change the codename and add your desired components.